# Basis for series that converge for all complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

Consider the set of power series that converge on all of $\mathbb C$. Clearly that set forms a vector space.

Now I noticed that all functions I know which are in that space (that is, all functions that can be defined by an everywhere-converging power series) are linear combinations of terms of the form
$$f_{n,\alpha}(x) = x^n\exp(\alpha x)$$
for some $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and some $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ (note that this includes the polynomials, with $\alpha=0$).

Now I wonder: Is this because all of them have that form, or is it just that the other functions in this space are not generally useful?

Therefore my question:

Is the set of functions $f_{n,\alpha}$ a basis of the vector space of all functions defined by a power series that converges on all of $\mathbb C$?

If not, is it possible to give a complete basis of that space in closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. First think about
$$ \int_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt: $$
it's an entire function, because it is the integral of an entire function, but infamously cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. You can then probably use some sort of differential Galois theory to prove that you can't build a finite set of primitives (likely the functions $\int_0^z e^{-t^n} \, dt$ are "differentially independent", or whatever it's called in this case).

There's also things like the [Weierstrass $\sigma$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSigmaFunction.html), and of course $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire when you decide what its value at $1$ is.